# Unable to create database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, maui

When running my program I get this exception: 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException: 'SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Tasks'.'

I followed the steps on the Microsoft docs to install EFcore, create the model and create the database. This did the trick on one of my other Maui projects but not on this one since I can't get it to to create the table 'Tasks'.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Task = Todo.Models.Task;


namespace Todo.Data
{
    class TaskContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public string DbPath { get; }

        public TaskContext()
        {
            var folder = Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData;
            var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(folder);
            DbPath = System.IO.Path.Join(path, "ToDo.db");
        }

        // The following configures EF to create a Sqlite database file in the
        // special "local" folder for your platform.
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");
    }
}



using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Todo.Models
{
    public class Task
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit: Adding Database.EnsureCreated() in the TaskContext constructor fixed it

Comment: which line throws the exception?  I don't see anything that tells it that `Tasks` is a table to be created in the db.

Comment: Not the answer, but using the word _Task_ for your table and objects is really a bad choice given the C# keyword _Task_  I think you will have a lot of readability problems

Comment: Try do not use `Task` as name of the entity class. You will have collision with System.Threading.Task.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, that is why I have "using Task = Todo.Models.Task;"

Comment: Do you ensure that somewhere in your code `Database.EnsureCreated()` is called? Or migrations applied by code or command line?

Comment: Just don't do that if you don't want to solve another issues in your code. And actually we do not see how do you create database.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks, adding Database.EnsureCreated() did the job. I had it in the taskcontext constructor before and it didn't work but now it does for some reason.